# Directory given in a variable gets never reached

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

There are two variables in my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file, both of them are used in the same script line:

```yaml
variables:
  TEST_SERVER: 10.11.12.13
  BUILD_DIR: "/var/www/distrib"

[...]

script:
  - ssh skipper@$TEST_SERVER 'ls -la $BUILD_DIR'
```

The server IP gets picked up correctly, but the directory gets never reached (and it exists, of course). The directory contents listed below are obviously user's home dir contents:

```
$ ssh skipper@$TEST_SERVER 'ls -la $BUILD_DIR'
Warning: Permanently added '10.11.12.13' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
total 48
drwxr-xr-x  5 skipper skipper 4096 Mar 12 12:03 .
drwxr-xr-x 16 root     root     4096 Mar 11 09:29 ..
-rw-------  1 skipper skipper 2056 Mar 18 09:43 .bash_history
-rw-r--r--  1 skipper skipper  220 Mar 11 09:29 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r--  1 skipper skipper 3771 Mar 11 09:29 .bashrc
drwx------  2 skipper skipper 4096 Mar 11 11:38 .cache
drwx------  3 skipper skipper 4096 Mar 11 11:38 .gnupg
-rw-r--r--  1 skipper skipper  807 Mar 11 09:29 .profile
drwx------  2 skipper root     4096 Mar 11 11:30 .ssh
-rw-------  1 skipper skipper 9800 Mar 12 12:03 .viminfo
```

I tried defining the directory variable with or without quotation marks, then calling it with double dollar sign (`$$BUILD_DIR`), but none of these attempts worked.

Any ideas what is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the single quotes might be messing with the script section somewhat, as everything inside the single quotes is preserved literally.

Using double quotes round the `ls` should resolve the issue.

```
ssh skipper@$TEST_SERVER "ls -la $BUILD_DIR"
```